# Getting Data on a table depending on another

Tags: sql, linq, entity-framework

Right now I have 3 Tables

```
**Users**
int Id
int Username

**Pages**
int Id
string content;

**Pages_Authors**
int Id
int Pages_Id
int User_Id
```

I'm trying to make a SQL / Linq statement where I can get the pages depending on the Pages_Author User_Id I input it. Like If my User_Id was 2, it would get all the pages where my User_Id is 2.

Comment: It should be done using navigation properties with LINQ set properly. Just `db.Users.First(x => x.Id == 2).Pages`.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't follow. I have 3 entities which are DbSet<Users> UsersEntity { get; set; }
public DbSet<Comics> ComicsEntity { get; set; }
public DbSet<Comics_Authors> ComicsAuthorEntity { get; set; }

I don't see how youre statement above would give me all the pages according to the User_Id I specefied in the Authors table.

Comment: http://coding.abel.nu/2012/06/dont-use-linqs-join-navigate/

Comment: Alright, I finally got it! Thanks!